# how to disable identifying network in windows

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, android, wifi-configuration

When i change the wireless network to another like my own phone's wireless network the connection is "limited" for like 2 minutes. during this time i see "identifying network..." This happens every time I connect not just once. Is there a way to disable this and just connect and have the internet working instantly like in macos?

Answer (score 0):

From the run dialog (Windows)+r:

type services.msc + (return)

Disable the "Network List Service"

Reboot.

This should fix the issue.